# Calculate Gamma and Vega of a portfolio of convertible bonds

Tags: gamma, vega, convertible-bond

I am being asked to calculate the gamma and vega of an existing portfolio of convertible bonds. does anyone has a documentation of direction that i could use to get going pls? This is a premiere for me.
Any help would be good.